# Very long time of saving data in Firestore Database

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have some issue with saving data into Cloud Firestore with using Swift (iOS),
there is not much data, it is just data like that:

```
["dryingPhase": {
    colorChange = "48.68%";
    colorChangeInSeconds = 185;
    yellowing = "32.89%";
    yellowingInSeconds = 125;
}, "roastProfileLink": https://[DOMAIN]?CAESEGMFf6FUa0XDn04lVwdUPskaFEtva2UgRmlsdGVyIG1lZGl1bSArIgUIABD0AyIGCIgIEPYPIgYIxg8QwRMiBgiDFxCIFCIGCN0dELMTKgUIABDAASoGCN0dEKwBMAE6BgiuJBC/AUImChxwQ0wyMm93cDdmWkljVU1Ed3pvTXZYYWx0ZVgyEgAaACIAKAA=, "creatorID": "Er8ygYHRy4RnMKRxH9Wvzl73Vf23", "dateCreated": 2021-11-13 11:19:28 +0000, "totalRoastTimeInSeconds": 380, "coffeeID": "IQQ7BlFXFysBAeStZndY", "recipeDescription": "57u787976896789", "dateLastEdited": 2021-11-13 11:19:28 +0000, "roastProfileID": "472A1D9E42124DC49618FCEF77CBB4DA", "recipeType": Filter, "description": This recommended recipe begins with a steady and gradual increase in temperature, creating an even and long drying phase. The moderate peak temperature is reached right at first crack and decreases steadily through the development phase, about 1 minute and 30 seconds. The result is a coffee with a medium roast degree and a low development. , "flavour": {
    acidity = 3;
    bitterness = 3;
    body = 3;
}, "recipeID": "472A1D9E42124DC49618FCEF77CBB4DA", "roastDegreeLevel": 3, "isRecommended": false, "developmentPhase": {
    developmentTime = "77.32%";
    firstCrack = "76.32%";
    firstCrackInSeconds = 290;
}, "roastDevelopmentLevel": 1]
```

I am trying to save new object to existing collection, I am using method:

```
print("start saving", Date())
newCoffeeRecipe.setData(data, merge: false) { error in
print("finish saving", Date())
….
}
```

> start saving 2021-11-13 11:15:13 +0000

> finish saving 2021-11-13 11:16:51 +0000

> start saving 2021-11-13 11:19:28 +0000

> finish saving 2021-11-13 11:21:08 +0000

as you can see the data saving time is over 90 seconds!
what is the reason of that?
My plan is Blaze Pay as you go
Usage from last 30 days:

Reads
42M total

Writes
31M total

Deletes
3.5K total

Comment: Why's stopping you from using `addDocument(data:)`?

Comment: @ElTomato Would that make any difference of the performance of the write operation? If not, why do you think it is good to change to `addDocument`? If so, can you explain a bit more about what difference you experienced with that approach?

Comment: There is no difference in time response between setData(data, merge: false, completion: { }) and addDocument(data: data, completion: { })

For addDocument I also get 80-90sec delay in response